# How to find if a method is implementing specific interface

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a MehtodBase of a method and I need to know if that method is an implementation of a specific interface.
So if I have the following class:

```
class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public void SomeMethod();
}
```

Implementing the interface:

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    void SomeMethod();
}
```

I want to be able to discover at runtime (using reflection) if a certain method implements IMyInterface.

Comment: Do you mean you want to determine if `MyClass.SomeMethod()` is an explicit implementation of `IMyInterface.SomeMethod()`?

Comment: No necessarily explicit but I want ot know if a methodbase object I got is an implementation of a specific interface method.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`GetInterfaceMap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfacemap.aspx) for this.

```
InterfaceMapping map = typeof(MyClass).GetInterfaceMap(typeof(IMyInterface));

foreach (var method in map.TargetMethods)
{
    Console.WriteLine(method.Name + " implements IMyInterface");
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`Type.GetInterfaceMap()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfacemap.aspx) for that:

```
bool Implements(MethodInfo method, Type iface)
{
    return method.ReflectedType.GetInterfaceMap(iface).TargetMethods.Contains(method);
}
```

Comment: This is good.  Of note is that InterfaceMapping is a struct, so you don't check it for null but rather catch an ArgumentException.

Answer (score -7):

if you dont have to use reflection, then dont.  it is not as performant as, say, using the the `is` operator or the `as` operator

```
class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public void SomeMethod();
}

if ( someInstance is IMyInterface ) dosomething();

var foo = someInstance as IMyInterface;
if ( foo != null ) foo.SomeMethod();
```

Comment: I want to know that a method supplied by reflection implements an interface - not call it

Comment: if you use is and it returns true, then you know that it implements your interface.

Comment: Again - I'm interested in querying methodbase in order to determine that the method is an implementation of the method in an interface not the instance.