# How to know if a MemberInfo is an explicit implementation of a property

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Imagine I have the code below.  How can I get by reflection the `MemberInfo/PropertyInfo` for the 'explicit' implementation of `Test.Name`?

Also, is there any way to programmatically know that a `MemberInfo` is an explicit implementation of an interface property?

```
public interface ITest
{
    string Title { get; set; }
}

public interface IExplicit
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Test : ITest,IExplicit
{

    public string Title { get; set; }

    string IExplict.Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Title;

        }
        set
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find if a method is implementing specific interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379276/how-to-find-if-a-method-is-implementing-specific-interface)

Comment: @Adriano it's not really a duplicate, because he asks how to figure out if it is implemented explicitly. Though I'd use the answer from the link and add a condition that it'd have to be private or differently named (or just private).

Comment: @jgauffin It's a valid question. I need it for instance to generate documentation (sandcastle-style).

Comment: @Alxandr I'm missing a point, is your question of the one of Karl?! :)

Comment: @Adriano it's a comment to your "possible duplicate of".

Comment: @jgauffin I need it so that I can implement a custom JSONContractResolver for Newtonsoft Json.net, such that explicit properties are automatically never serialized.

Comment: @Alxandr you're right, I still would have a "cancel submit for close" button...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Imagine you have this interface:

```
interface ITest
{
    bool MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Implemented in this class:

```
class Test : ITest
{
    bool ITest.MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's add this property to `Test` (note they have the *same* name):

```
public bool MyProperty { get; set; }
```

With a *plain* `GetProperties()` you won't get the explicit interface implementation (because it's always a private member):

```
int count = new Test().GetType().GetProperties().Length; // It's 1!
```

If you include both `Public` and `NonPublic` members you'll get both. To distinguish them you can rely first on name: the explicit implementation will contain the full interface name (so you can look for a `.`, it won't be there for a *normal* property because it's not an allowed char):

```
public static bool IsExplicitInterfaceImplementation(PropertyInfo property)
{
    return property.Name.Contains(".");
}
```

It's a little bit naive so you may want some extra check, you can assert that get method of that property will:

- Is `virtual` and `sealed`.
- Is `private`.
- Contains at least one dot.
- Won't start with `get_` or `_set`

Let's change code:

```
public static bool IsExplicitInterfaceImplementation(PropertyInfo property)
{
    // This check is not mandatory and not cross-languages.
    // How this method is named may vary
    if (!property.Name.Contains("."))
        return false;

    if (property.Name.StartsWith("get_"))
        return false;

    if (!property.GetMethod.IsFinal)
        return false;

    if (!property.GetMethod.IsVirtual)
        return false;

    if (!property.GetMethod.IsPrivate)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Of course not all these checks are needed, I think first two are enough to exclude most of compiler generated code.

If you know which interface may be explicitly implemented you'll find this question here on SO pretty useful: [How to find if a method is implementing specific interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379276/how-to-find-if-a-method-is-implementing-specific-interface)

**EDIT**
From comments I thought about this and I found there is not a proper way to do it, CLR does not apply any rule (AFAIK) because what's needed is just the link between interface method and class method (no matters how it's called). I suppose (but it may be relaxed or expanded for other languages, if someone would contribute with more tests I'll make this answer a wiki) this code may work in most cases (thanks Alxandr for the hint):

First generic function to check if a method (given a `MethodInfo`) is an explicit interface implementation or not.

What we can't assert:

- We can't use name (to check, for example ".") because it's implementation dependent (C# uses interfaceName.methodName but other languages do not).
- We can't rely on check for private because (for example) in C++/CLI it can be a public method (with another name) moreover an interface can be "hacked" to be internal but the implementer to be public (so method won't be public too).

What we may assert:

- An explicit interface implementation is always sealed and virtual. Maybe its' not true for all languages so we may relax this rule.
- If a method has not the same name of the method declared in the interface it implements then it's an explicit implementation.

This is the code:

```
public static bool IsExplicitInterfaceImplementation(MethodInfo method)
{
    // Check all interfaces implemented in the type that declares
    // the method we want to check, with this we'll exclude all methods
    // that don't implement an interface method
    var declaringType = method.DeclaringType;
    foreach (var implementedInterface in declaringType.GetInterfaces())
    {
        var mapping = declaringType.GetInterfaceMap(implementedInterface);

        // If interface isn't implemented in the type that owns
        // this method then we can ignore it (for sure it's not
        // an explicit implementation)
        if (mapping.TargetType != declaringType)
            continue;

        // Is this method the implementation of this interface?
        int methodIndex = Array.IndexOf(mapping.TargetMethods, method);
        if (methodIndex == -1)
            continue;

        // Is it true for any language? Can we just skip this check?
        if (!method.IsFinal || !method.IsVirtual)
            return false;

        // It's not required in all languages to implement every method
        // in the interface (if the type is abstract)
        string methodName = "";
        if (mapping.InterfaceMethods[methodIndex] != null)
            methodName = mapping.InterfaceMethods[methodIndex].Name;

        // If names don't match then it's explicit
        if (!method.Name.Equals(methodName, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

With this auxiliary function to do the check for properties:

```
public static bool IsExplicitInterfaceImplementation(PropertyInfo property)
{
    // At least one accessor must exists, I arbitrary check first for
    // "get" one. Note that in Managed C++ (not C++ CLI) these methods
    // are logically separated so they may follow different rules (one of them
    // is explicit and the other one is not). It's a pretty corner case
    // so we may just ignore it.
    if (property.GetMethod != null)
        return IsExplicitInterfaceImplementation(property.GetMethod);

    return IsExplicitInterfaceImplementation(property.SetMethod);
}
```

Comment: No problem. I really like your answer. I'm in the middle of creating a documentation-miner and this was useful. Though I'm wondering about one thing, is there any cases where the property's name will have a `.` and also have a name that starts with `get_`? Also, how about explicit interface-implementations from VB.NET (ie. all implementations from VB.NET), or C++/CLI?

Comment: I think I might actually have found a better solution. Check if the method implements an interface by use of interface-maps (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379276/how-to-find-if-a-method-is-implementing-specific-interface), and that it is private (or alternatively that the name differ in the case of VB/C++ where you have a public method that implements an interface-method with another name, if this is indeed doable).

Comment: @Adriano can you give an example of non-explicit member, which have `.` in name?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky first thing that comes to my mind (but I **suppose** there can be more): the `<Module>` class in mixed C++/CLI assemblies. Method names are full of _garbage_ there.

Comment: @Adriano how does it relates to C#?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky because in C# you can consume them

Comment: @Adriano very interesting - can you give me a link to such methods (with dot in names) usage?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky no, we're talking about something different...the point is that methods exist, they can be compiler generated (C++ generates more of that) or handwritten IL. Other languages may generate them or not (in some languages it may even be allowed by the language). I just suppose IF you're writing a method to detect an explicit interface implementation THEN you have to handle it (in C++/CLI for example they don't have the dot at all...)

Comment: @Adriano sorry, didn't get you. I just think that all these conditions - not final, not private, not virtual, are useless. And I'm trying to figure out whether I missed something or not

Comment: @lazyberezovsky maybe not. I mean: names can be anything, rules that apply to C# don't need to apply to other languages and compiler generated code (both from MS or 3rd) can produce anything. The **only** secure way to check if a method is an explicit interface implementation is to check how interfaces it implements are mapped to its methods. A more dirty solution should check as much as possible of the other conditions (because each one individually is not enough).

Comment: @Adriano why each one individually is not enough? Dot in name, for example :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky :) because in, for example, C++ is not the rule. If he has to check only C# generated code then...yes, it's enough (but I never checked naming convention for compiler generated code so I wouldn't write it on the stone...)

Comment: You don't need `.GetType()` after `.DeclaringType` in the beginning.

Comment: MrTA you're right, that error stayed there 3 years! Thank you

Comment: In the `IsExplicitInterfaceImplementation` last version in last check `interfaceMethodName` is not declared I suppose `methodName` should be there instead.

Comment: You're right, they should add unit testing for code snippets!

Answer (score 2):

Use `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic` binding flags to get members which declared explicitly. Also you need to specify full name for explicit members, if you want to get them by name:

```
Type type = typeof(Test);
var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
var property = type.GetProperty("Namespace.IExplicit.Name", flags);
```

You can use this fact to filter only explicitly implemented memebers:

```
var explicitMembers = type.GetMembers(flags).Where(m => m.Name.Contains("."));
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If both your interfaces and classes reside in the same namespace,</strike> You could try this:

```
var interfaces = (typeof(Test)).GetInterfaces();
var p = typeof(Test).GetProperties(
    BindingFlags.Instance |
    BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var result = interfaces.SelectMany(i => i.GetMembers())
        .Select(m =>
        {
            var name = m.DeclaringType.FullName +"."+ m.Name;
            Console.WriteLine(name);
            return name;
        })
        .Intersect(p.Select(m =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Name);
            return m.Name;
        }))
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the PropertyInfo for any existing implementation (impicit or explicit) of the specific interface property use the following code:

```
var pInfoName = typeof(IExplicit).GetProperty("Name");
//...
Test tObj = new Test() { Title = "Test" };
string explicitName = (string)pInfoName.GetValue(tObj, new object[] { });
```

To **classify** the existing PropertyInfo use the approaches shown in @Adriano answer.