# Can I get the interface that a method is implementing via Java reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, interface

I am writing a messaging component and for certain reasons I need to find out which methods of a class are qualified to be called by the messaging component. Among other criteria, these methods need to be implementing a particular interface. How do I find out exactly these methods via reflection? I do have access to th class but I must not rely on the method names. There could be similar methods in the class that have the same name but not implement the desired (or any) interface. Example:

```
interface A
{
   long set(Object object)
}

class B implements A
{
   public long set(Object object)
   {
      System.out.println("I am the method they are looking for!");
   }

   public void set(int i, int j)
   {
      System.out.println("I am not the qualifying method!");
   }
}
```

So, in short words, I want to find the first method through reflection but not the second one. Is this possible in Java?

Comment: If you know class B implements interface A, (can be checked from the class), you can just loop over all A's methods using `A.class.getMethods()`, and invoke them without problem on an instance of the class B

Comment: Well, you can always check whether the class implements that interface, and get the methods declared by that interface.

Comment: [Yes it is possible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getDeclaringClass--). I would expect any competent programmer to have been able to find this for himself frankly.

Comment: You are right. I was coming from the method and looking for something like Method.getDeclaringInterface() or similar. But it's indeed a good idea to come from the interface and invoke the interface with the actual instance. Thanks!

Comment: Based on the pattern of downvotes, I think someone will only be satisfied if they get code handed to them on a plate.

Comment: I just would like to stress that nobody asked for code here. The question can be answered with something like "Yes, take a look at method XYZ in the reflection API, it does exactly what you are looking for" or "No, unfortunately, you have to find your own solution. One of them could be iterating through the interface methods and calling them given class B's instance". The advice of @Ferrybig and Thomas were the most helpful here.

Comment: @Wombat Just to expand my previous comment, If you don't know what interfaces your class implements, you can call [`Class.getInterfaces()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces--) to get a list of all the interfaces

Answer (score 0):

Yes ... and no.

Traverse the DAG of superclasses and interfaces of the class, calling  `getDeclaredMethods()` for each to obtain a set of `Method` objects declared in interfaces.  Then look for matches between that set and the set of declared methods for the class itself.

One problem is that a given method in the class *could* be implementing abstract methods declared by multiple interfaces.

A second problem is deciding on the correct (for your application!) method matching semantic, and implementing it.  (Note that your example is just an example.  It doesn't specify any semantics.)

Answer (score -1):

You can establish a list of interfaces declaring a method using:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class B extends D implements A {

    public Long set(Object object) {
        System.out.println("I am the method they are looking for!");
        return (long) 0;
    }

    public void set(int i, int j) {
        System.out.println("I am not the qualifying method!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        Method methodToCheck = B.class.getDeclaredMethod("set", Object.class);
        List<Class<?>> declaringInterfaces = searchForDeclaringInterfaces(methodToCheck, B.class);
        System.out.println("The method " + methodToCheck + " is declared in these interfaces:");
        for (Class<?> c : declaringInterfaces) {
            System.out.println(c.getCanonicalName());
        }

    }

    public static List<Class<?>> searchForDeclaringInterfaces(Method methodToCheck, Class<?> clazz)
            throws NoSuchMethodException {
        if (clazz == null) {
            return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
        }
        LinkedList<Class<?>> declaringInterfaces = new LinkedList<>();
        for (Class<?> c : clazz.getInterfaces()) {
            Method methodFromInterface = searchMethods(c.getDeclaredMethods(), methodToCheck.getName(),
                    methodToCheck.getParameterTypes());
            if (methodFromInterface != null) {
                declaringInterfaces.add(c);
            }
        }
        declaringInterfaces.addAll(searchForDeclaringInterfaces(methodToCheck, clazz.getSuperclass()));
        return declaringInterfaces;
    }

    private static Method searchMethods(Method[] methods, String name, Class<?>[] parameterTypes) {
        Method res = null;
        String internedName = name.intern();
        for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
            Method m = methods[i];
            if (m.getName() == internedName && arrayContentsEq(parameterTypes, m.getParameterTypes())
                    && (res == null || res.getReturnType().isAssignableFrom(m.getReturnType())))
                res = m;
        }

        return res;
    }

    private static boolean arrayContentsEq(Object[] a1, Object[] a2) {
        if (a1 == null) {
            return a2 == null || a2.length == 0;
        }

        if (a2 == null) {
            return a1.length == 0;
        }

        if (a1.length != a2.length) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
            if (a1[i] != a2[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}

interface A extends C {
    public Number set(Object object);
}

interface C {
    Number set(Object object);
}

class D implements C {

    @Override
    public Number set(Object object) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

This will print:

```
The method public java.lang.Long B.set(java.lang.Object) is declared in these interfaces:
A
C
```

It print all interfaces that are somwhere in the tree of class B and declare this method.

Comment: I'm surprised. A similar question has been asked, however for C#, and a satisfying and precise answer was given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379276/how-to-find-if-a-method-is-implementing-specific-interface

Comment: @Wombat - excellent.  So translate the code in that answer into Java, and you are done :-)

Comment: @StephenC I wish I could but there is no Type.GetInterfaceMap() in Java.

Comment: You don't need all this. [One method call](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getDeclaringClass--) is sufficient.

Comment: *"I wish I could but there is no Type.GetInterfaceMap() in Java."* .... so write one!  We've explained what you need to do.  This is a Q&A site, not a free coding service.